# Using bindings in DataTrigger condition

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

Let's say I have the following simple classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class PersonHolder
{
    public Person CurrentPerson { get; set; }
    public int ActiveId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a grid with an instance of class PersonHolder as `DataContext`, and in the grid I have a `StackPanel` which is bound to the `CurrentPerson` of `PersonHolder` - showing its data:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="PersonPanel" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />            
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

So - to the question: How can I give the `StackPanel` a green background when the `CurrentPerson` has an `Id` matching the `ActiveId` of the `PersonHolder` (*yeah, very useful, but this is just an extremely simplified example..*). My thought is that this is something one uses a trigger for, but can I use bindings in my trigger condition value? If so I could do something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Foo">
    <StackPanel x:Name="PersonPanel" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Id}" Value="{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=ActiveId}">
                <Setter TargetName="PersonPanel" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

But this doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't use a binding on the Value property, but you can get around this by using a [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx). I would define my `Trigger` in a `Style` in e.g. the Window.Resources, which would give something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:SomeMultiConverter x:Key="someMultiConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="someStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="Red" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someMultiConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="Id"></Binding>
                        <Binding ElementName="Foo" Path="DataContext.ActiveId"></Binding>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="StackPanel.Background" Value="Green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style> 
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="Foo">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentPerson}" Style="{StaticResource someStyle}" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

See [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130111212302/http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-multibindings) for an example on `MultiBinding` and `IMultiValueConverter`. They're fairly easy to write.