# Highlight one item in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm displaying `Cars` in a DataGrid and would like to highlight one special car, the `CurrentlySelectedCar`.

When the user double clicks on a car, this car is saved as `CurrentlySelectedCar` in my MainViewModel. Now, whenever the user comes back to the DataGrid, I would like to highlight this car = row, e.g. by using a red background.

I have found out how to highlight rows in a DataGrid based on certain values, but in my case, all I have is the CurrentlySelectedCar.

My First try:

```
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- not working-->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentlySelectedCar}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

My second try:

```
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- not working either, "Binding can only be set on DependencyProperty of DependecyObject"-->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Guid}" Value="{Binding CurrentlySelectedCar.Guid}" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

**How can I highlight the row with this information?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to do something like this described in this answer: [Using bindings in DataTrigger condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239839/using-bindings-in-datatrigger-condition)

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Value="True">
      <DataTrigger.Binding>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someMultiConverter}">
          <Binding Path="Guid"></Binding>
          <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Datagrid}}" Path="CurrentlySelectedCar.Guid"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
      </DataTrigger.Binding>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You have to write a multiconverter that return true if the two Guid are equals.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead, since each datagrid row has an IsSelected property, you can bind to it directly.

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="False">
   <DataGrid.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" >
                   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
             </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
  </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

**Updated response**

The problem right now is your DataContext is the DataGridRow, and it doesn't have access to the MainViewModel. You can address this by passing the DataGridRow to a converter that is aware of the current MainViewModel. However, it is a lot of code, and is barely comprehensible.

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:IsCurrentlySelectedCarConverter x:Key="IsCurrentlySelectedCarConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
   ...
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 
        Path=DataContext, 
        Converter={StaticResource IsCurrentlySelectedCarConverter}}" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
  </DataTrigger>

</Window>
```

Here's corresponding converter

```
public class IsCurrentlySelectedConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public MainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set;}

   public object Convert(object value, ....)
   {
      return (value == MainViewModel.CurrentlySelectedCar);              
   }
}
```

and you'll need to wire in the converter's MainViewModel manually in your view

```
this.Resources["IsCurrentlySelectedCarConverter"].MainViewModel = _mainViewModel;
```

and at this point you'd have to question the maintainability of the monster that has been created.

It may be better to replace each `Car` with a `CarViewModel` so that it has a property called `IsSelected` and you can maintain that in code. The following in my opinion is easier to follow what is actually going on.

```
public class CarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      public MainViewModel { get; set; }

      public bool IsSelected { get { return this == MainViewModel.CurrentlySelectedCar; } }

      // Call RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected") whenever
      // CurrentlySelectedCar is changed
      public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
      {
          if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
      }
}
```

Comment: That would only mark the selected row in red. In my case, some other row than the CurrentlySelectedCar-row might be selected - still, the CurrentlySelectedCar-row should be red.